# Arguments in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, callback, arguments

I have a little library, here is fragment of a function i use

```
HashManager.prototype.on = function(hash, callback) {

    if(hash[0] == '#') { hash = hash.substr(1); }

    if( typeof this.observers[hash] !== 'object' ) {
        this.observers[hash] = [];
    }

    this.observers[hash].push(callback);

    return this.observers[hash][this.observers[hash].length-1];
};
```

here is my arr

```
    var ajaxURLS = {
    '#!o_kompanii': '/apages/about.html',
    '#!production': '/apages/production.html',
    '#!gde_kupit': '/apages/gde_kupit.html',
    '#!hozyaike_na_zametku': '/apages/hozyaike_na_zametku.html',
    '#!news': '/apages/news.html',
    '#!contacts': '/apages/contacts.html',
    '#!kurochka_po_zernyshku': '/apages/kurochka_po_zernyshku.html'

    };
```

and here is my loop

```
   var HM = new window.HashManager();
   $.each(ajaxURLS,function(hash, uri) {
        HM.on(hash, function(uri,hash) {
        console.log(uri);
        console.log(hash);
        });
  });
```

my issue is that console.log always print me a last key and value of my array
how can i pass arguments correctly?
thanks a lot, best regards

Answer (score 0):

**[Javascript closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)** should help you:

```
var HM = new window.HashManager();
   $.each(ajaxURLS, function(_hash, _uri) {
        HM.on(_hash, (function(uri,hash) {
            console.log(uri);
            console.log(hash);
        })(_hash, _uri));
  });
```